# InvalidTokenError: Invalid Compact JWS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, authentication, auth0, auth0-js

Error:

```
PS C:\Users\91955\Desktop\Full-stack-real-estate-youtube\server> node index.js
Server is running on port 8000
InvalidTokenError: Invalid Compact JWS
    at C:\Users\91955\Desktop\Full-stack-real-estate-youtube\server\node_modules\express-oauth2-jwt-bearer\dist\index.js:300:19
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async C:\Users\91955\Desktop\Full-stack-real-estate-youtube\server\node_modules\express-oauth2-jwt-bearer\dist\index.js:403:24
```

```
import { auth } from "express-oauth2-jwt-bearer";

const jwtCheck = auth({
  audience: "http://localhost:8000",
  issuerBaseURL: "https:XXXXXXXXXXXXXX.us.auth0.com",
  tokenSigningAlg: "RS256",
});

export default jwtCheck;
```

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import "./index.css";
import App from "./App";
import { Auth0Provider } from "@auth0/auth0-react";

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root")).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Auth0Provider
      domain="XXXXXXXl.us.auth0.com"
      clientId="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXDdp"
      authorizationParams={{
        redirect_uri: "http://localhost:5173",
      }}
      audience="http://localhost:8000"
      scope="openid profile email"
    >
      <App />
    </Auth0Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

Auth0 dashboard
[image]

So the problem is occurring here in all the `POST` requests. Whenever I try to `POST` something, it throws `InvalidTokenError: Invalid Compact JWS`.

Api.js file :

```
import axios from "axios";
import dayjs from "dayjs";
import { toast } from "react-toastify";

export const api = axios.create({
  baseURL: "http://localhost:8000/api",
});

export const getAllProperties = async () => {
  try {
    const response = await api.get("/residency/allresd", {
      timeout: 10 * 1000,
    });

    if (response.status === 400 || response.status === 500) {
      throw response.data;
    }
    return response.data;
  } catch (error) {
    toast.error("Something went wrong");
    throw error;
  }
};

export const getProperty = async (id) => {
  try {
    const response = await api.get(`/residency/${id}`, {
      timeout: 10 * 1000,
    });

    if (response.status === 400 || response.status === 500) {
      throw response.data;
    }
    return response.data;
  } catch (error) {
    toast.error("Something went wrong");
    throw error;
  }
};

export const createUser = async (email, token) => {
  try {
    await api.post(
      `/user/register`,
      { email },
      {
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
        },
      }
    );
  } catch (error) {
    toast.error("Something went wrong, Please try again");
    throw error;
  }
};

export const bookVisit = async (date, propertyId, email, token) => {
  try {
    await api.post(
      `/user/bookVisit/${propertyId}`,
      {
        email,
        id: propertyId,
        date: dayjs(date).format("DD/MM/YYYY"),
      },
      {
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
        },
      }
    );
  } catch (error) {
    toast.error("Something went wrong, Please try again");
    throw error;
  }
};

export const removeBooking = async (id, email, token) => {
  try {
    await api.post(
      `/user/removeBooking/${id}`,
      {
        email,
      },
      {
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
        },
      }
    );
  } catch (error) {
    toast.error("Something went wrong, Please try again");

    throw error;
  }
};

export const toFav = async (id, email, token) => {
  try {
    await api.post(
      `/user/toFav/${id}`,
      {
        email,
      },
      {
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
        },
      }
    );
  } catch (e) {
    throw e;
  }
};

export const getAllFav = async (email, token) => {
  if (!token) return;
  try {
    const res = await api.post(
      `/user/allFav`,
      {
        email,
      },
      {
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
        },
      }
    );

    return res.data["favResidenciesID"];
  } catch (e) {
    toast.error("Something went wrong while fetching favs");
    throw e;
  }
};

export const getAllBookings = async (email, token) => {
  if (!token) return;
  try {
    const res = await api.post(
      `/user/allBookings`,
      {
        email,
      },
      {
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
        },
      }
    );
    return res.data["bookedVisits"];
  } catch (error) {
    toast.error("Something went wrong while fetching bookings");
    throw error;
  }
};

export const createResidency = async (data, token) => {
  console.log(data);
  try {
    const res = await api.post(
      `/residency/create`,
      {
        data,
      },
      {
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
        },
      }
    );
  } catch (error) {
    throw error;
  }
};
```

I tried this:

```
 redirect_uri: window.location.origin,
```